# How to retrieve data from log files using linux commands and add to array

Tags: php, arrays, linux, logging

I have a log file with content like this

```
2018/01/14 12:27:27|get_offers|ok|1678537191|64.233.173.132|info=wifi
2018/01/14 12:27:27|get_offers|ok|1678537191|64.233.173.132|info=wifi
2018/01/14 12:27:27|get_offers|ok|1678537191|64.233.173.132|info=wifi
```

I'm trying to retrieve data/ offer/ status/ number/ IP separately one by one.
I'm using PHP Yii framework for that and in the program running linux commands.

Commands

```
 $dateCmd = "cat " . $file_names_str . "| awk -F '|' '{ print $1}'";
 $descCmd = "cat " . $file_names_str . "| awk -F '|' '{ print $2}'";
 $statusCmd = "cat " . $file_names_str . "| awk -F '|' '{ print $3}'";
 $mobileCmd = "cat " . $file_names_str . "| awk -F '|' '{ print $4}'";
 $ipCmd = "cat " . $file_names_str . "| awk -F '|' '{ print $5}'";
```

Execution Part

```
 $date = shell_exec($dateCmd);
 $desc = shell_exec($descCmd);
 $status = shell_exec($statusCmd);
 $mobile = shell_exec($mobileCmd);
 $ip = shell_exec($ipCmd);
```

And finally i want a array like this.and encode as JSON. following array contains dummy data.

```
$rec = [
            [
                'date' => '2018-02-01',
                'desc' => 'test descrip',
                'status' => 'true',
                'mobile' => '2145786695',
                'ip' => '127.168.0.1',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2018-02-01',
                'desc' => 'test descrip2',
                'status' => 'true',
                'mobile' => '2145786695',
                'ip' => '127.168.0.1',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2018-02-01',
                'desc' => 'test descrip2',
                'status' => 'true',
                'mobile' => '2145786695',
                'ip' => '127.168.0.1',
            ],

        ];


        $enc =  CJSON::encode($rec);
        echo $enc;
```

But in this case it do not retrieve data as i wish. I'm new to linux and i just want to get records line by line like this image.
[image: expected output]

please help me to solve this.

Comment: I wouldn't switch between linux and php like that: If you have a valid csv file where the separator is a `|` symbol, it is probably easier to use `fgetcsv()` to read and parse it.

Comment: Why so complicated - why not do everything in one PHP script? Like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574944/parse-a-log-file-with-regex-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution in PHP:

```
$lines = file("logfile.log");
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  $parts = explode("|", $line);
  $result[] = [
    'date' => $parts[0],
    'desc' => $parts[1],
    'status' => $parts[2],
    'mobile' => $parts[3],    
    'ip' => $parts[4],
    'info' => $parts[5]
  ];
}

header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: there is an extend of these question. there are multiple log files. and i want to do this at once by running through those files same as your answer and add to one array. how can i do that?

Comment: You can read an array of all files matching certain criteria with glob(). Then loop through them and put the contents in a subarray for each file. This what you need to add for the new loop: `foreach (glob("*.log") as $filename)`, in in the loop change `$result[] = ` to `$result[$filename][] =`